# Taking user input and assigning it to object

Tags: java, string, object

I'm using the scanner to take user input and assign it to an object. I know string is an extension of object class so it should be a simple assignment. Here is what I've tried.

```
string name = s.nextLine();// or s.next();
object obj = name;// or JOSN.parse(name);
```

Here is my code. I've put one arraylist instead another arrraylist.

```
        trans = new List<Transition>(nos);

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            List<Transition>innerList = trans.get(i);
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                String state = s.next();
                Transition reg = innerList.get(j).add(state);
         }}
```

The error i get is 'type mismatch cant convert type string to Transition', but Transition is just an object.

Comment: post some more code, what is innerList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         OBJECT
       /        \
  Transition   String
```

This is how the hierarchy looks like.

`Transition is a subclass of Object`, just like how `String is a subclass of Object`.

If two classes are in the same hierarchy chain, then an instance of the subclass can be safely cast to an instance of the superclass. In this case, `Transition and String` are not in the same chain.

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052943/object-typecasting-difference#27053039) for more information. I asked question for you only basically and got downvote. :)

Comment: @Will please have a look for the answer

Answer (score 0):

When ever we are doing casting it **must have IS-A Relation**. Means, **String IS-A Object** and **Transition IS-A Object**.

**But** In this when we try to make a relationship on String and Transition we See, **Transition NOT(IS-A) String**.

This will give to you casting problem, we must remember whenever we are trying any Casting it **must be in hierarchy, Having IS-A relation** with the other.